# Get song title from sd card to display in android >2.3 or 4.0

Tags: android

I am able to display song tile fetched from local sd card.The issue is when i see the songs list of mine and default music player, i found that song name has trimed if there is some extra string(string could be third -party site or movie name.).how can i achieve it.?

```
    tempCursor = ((Activity)context).managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);

            tempCursor.moveToFirst();
            ArrayList<Song> list = new ArrayList<Song>();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempCursor.getCount(); i++) {

                id = temp    Cursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
                artist = temp    Cursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                name = temp    Cursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                data = temp    Cursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                albumName = temp    Cursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                albumId = temp    Cursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
```

Notice the difference in the song titles:

[image: Screenshot one]
[image: Screenshot one]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rewrite**

Thanks for the screenshots I see the problem, simply change this:

```
name = tempCursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

to this:

```
name = tempCursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
```

**Addition from comments**

I cannot see what songs don't have Titles so I'll offer this:

```
name = tempCursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
if(name.isEmpty())
    name = tempCursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE));
if(name.isEmpty())
    name = tempCursor.getString(tempCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

I am unable to re-create what you describe and don't have much information to work with, hope this works.

Comment: not all songs contains that string...above code all song titles if it is song name is valid also..

Comment: I am confused by your question, since "I am able to display song tile", but "not all songs contains that string". Could you be more specific in your original question?

Comment: i dnt knw how to show pics..but song title displayed thru my above code and title displayed in default media player is different..how?

Comment: Click "Edit" in your question then find the image of a picture (in the toolbar that starts with: Bold, Italic, ... { }, Image, etc) and follow the prompts, otherwise simply post them on imgur.com and copy the links to your question.

Comment: i have added the link...please check

Comment: Forgive the simple nature of the question, but were they listed before? I don't know how selecting a different column like this would change the length of the cursor.

Comment: I hav just replaced title in place of display name. few songs missing

Comment: hey user 421 please tell me how did you get the songimages with song...i tried but i didnt get!!!!!!!!